# Dynamically added button not working properly ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, button, event-handling

I am trying to add a button to each row that when clicked will open a new panel and close the other but it just goes back to the index panel. (These buttons show up on the productsPanel and I want them to open the moreInfoPanel)

```
Button moreInfo = new Button();
moreInfo.Text = "Details";
moreInfo.ID = "info_" + x.ToString();
moreInfo.Click += new EventHandler(moreInfoClicked);
moreInfo.CommandName = dataRow["ARCHIVE_ID_NUMBER"].ToString();
moreInfo.CommandArgument = dataRow["ARCHIVE_ID_NUMBER"].ToString();
moreInfo.ControlStyle.CssClass = "moreInfoButton";

cell.Controls.Add(moreInfo);
row.Cells.Add(cell);


product.Rows.Add(row);
x += 1;

}
}
protected void moreInfoClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    indexPanel.Visible = false;
    productPanel.Visible = false;
    moreInfoPanel.Visible = true;

    Button moreInfoBtn = (Button)sender;
    var moreInfoChoice = moreInfoBtn.CommandArgument;

    moreInfo.InnerText = moreInfoChoice.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Is there anything in `Page_Load()` which might be causing this?

Comment: All it does in the Page_Load() is make the indexPanel visible and the rest hidden

Comment: And... Isn't the problem that the index panel is visible and the rest are hidden?  Seems likely that would be where it's happening.

Comment: Well yes but I want the button click to hide the index panel and make the more info panel visible. I've done this with other panels in the project but this one just has dynamically added buttons vs. hard-coded and I cant get these ones to work

Comment: When you debug this, what exactly is happening?  Is the click event not executing at all?  Is it executing but the load event is overwriting its changes?  Something else?

Comment: It seems like it is just going back to the Page_Load event and not executing the function on the click

Comment: It will definitely execute `Page_Load`, but it should also execute the click handler afterward.  It's been a while since I've had to use forms, I don't recall if there's any hoops to jump through for adding a click handler like this.  Maybe try this syntax?:  `moreInfo.Click += moreInfoClicked;`

Comment: Is there a way to run the function without running pageload? Like can I make it a different type of button like a LinkButton?

Comment: `Page_Load` executes every time the page is loaded.  So in order to not run `Page_Load` you would need to move the code to some other resource, such as an AJAX call to a Web Method or API method of some kind?  There may be a variety of options.  But it seems like a lot of re-structuring.  If the goal is to not use the functionality of forms then moving away from WebForms entirely would be the way to go.